# Can I live in Spain under a French contract?

Tags: employment, payroll-taxes, france, spain

Since July, I'm working remotely from Spain for a French company under a French contract. I'm Spanish, I've never lived in France. All of the salary related taxes are payed to the French government.

I know I'll have to do some kind of income tax in Spain, but I'm not sure if my situation is legal or what kind of taxes I'll have to pay.

**Update**

These are the links to the *Double Taxation Treaty* between Spain and France

[French](http://www.elitax.com/wp-content/plugins/google-document-embedder/load.php?d=http%3A%2F%2Felitax.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F02%2FFrance-Spain.pdf)

[Spanish](http://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1997-12729)

From what I understand, Article 15 is what affects me. Truth is, Legal text is beyond my capacity, I don't understand its meaning even in my own language, but I tend to interpret that I shouldn't pay taxes in France. I'll definitely look for legal advice.

Comment: This will be handled by the double taxation treaty between France and Spain. If any benefits are involved that would become a bit murky. I would go to an accountant who deals in taxation matters in both France and Spain to get an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Double Taxation Treaty, I've updated my question

Comment: That doesn't help. You need to get advice from a person dealing in these legal matters specifically. The documents I am assuming are in French and Spanish. Not sure if there are users here who understand legal language written in both Spanish and French

Comment: I haven't found them in english, unfortunately. I've already appointed a meeting with a professional counselor, I'll answer my own question after I talk to him

Comment: To answer the simplest question: Yes, you are allowed to live and work anywhere in the EU, and those two do not need to be in the same country. Of course, the downside (as you discovered) is that two sets of law apply, but both have to respect your EU rights.

Comment: I suggested changing “French employee” (which is not very clear and might suggest that you are a French citizen, which is apparently not accurate) to “under a French contract”, is this correct? Are you a cross-border worker (i.e. travelling to a workplace in France) or working remotely? It seems you already got an answer but this could make a difference and would be useful for other readers to know whether their situation is similar to yours or not.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks for the suggestions, I edited the title and specified that I'm a remote worker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a meeting with a financial advisor, these are the important points

- I have to file my Income Tax Return **only** in Spain, my country of 
  residence
- My French employer shouldn't deduce taxes from my net salary. I'm not sure if any tax or only those related to social security, national taxes, etc.

I hope this helps someone else

Comment: Note that until now there is no withholding of taxes in France (there are mandatory contribution to the health and other insurance systems but that's something else). It should be introduced in 2019. That should in itself change the applicable rules but you might need to monitor the situation to make sure your employers applies the rules correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped in my earlier comment, it should have read “That should *not* in itself change the applicable rules”.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In Spain they withhold the taxes from your salary, and in a yearly review they decide if they withholded too much or too little.

Comment: Any news on this? Any problem with the revenue service?

Comment: I didn't have issues with the revenue service, but I did have issues to use the French health or social systems, so in the end I moved to being a spanish freelancer. I invoice my company and that's it.